# Add a placeholder to angular {{}}

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have got this editable directive and it works lovely except it wont show text until the model has data inside it.

The method I have tried is this:

`{{option.title | Test}}`

I was hoping this would either show the `option.title`, but it doesn't.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<editable model="option.title">{{option.title | Test}}</editable>
```

Could I potentially use `ng-if`?

Here is the directive:

```
App.directive('editable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {model: '='},
        replace: false,
        template:
'<span>'+
    '<input type="text" ng-model="model" style="width: 100%; font-size: 18px" ng-show="edit" ng-enter="edit=false"></input>'+
        '<span ng-show="!edit">{{model}} <i class="fa fa-pencil" style="font-size:20px;"></i></span>'+
'</span>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.edit = false;
            element.bind('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(scope.edit = true);
                element.find('input').focus();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 1**

Try this:

```
App.directive('editable', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {model: '='},
        replace: false,
        template:
$compile('<span>'+
    '<input type="text" ng-model="model" style="width: 100%; font-size: 18px" ng-show="edit" ng-enter="edit=false"></input>'+
        '<span ng-show="!edit">{{model}} <i class="fa fa-pencil" style="font-size:20px;"></i></span>'+
'</span>'),
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.edit = false;
            element.bind('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(scope.edit = true);
                element.find('input').focus();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**EDIT 2**

Try initialize variable as:

```
App.directive('editable', function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {model: '='},
            replace: false,
            template:
    $compile('<span>'+
        '<input type="text" ng-model="model" style="width: 100%; font-size: 18px" ng-show="edit" ng-enter="edit=false"></input>'+
            '<span ng-show="!edit">{{model}} <i class="fa fa-pencil" style="font-size:20px;"></i></span>'+
    '</span>'),
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.edit = false;
                scope.model = '';
                element.bind('click', function() {
                    scope.$apply(scope.edit = true);
                    element.find('input').focus();
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

**EDIT 3**

Try:

```
<editable ng-init="option={title:''};" model="option.title">{{option.title | Test}}</editable>
```

Comment: That removed the element all together, The edit works fine, Its just the fact that {{option.title}} has no text inside until typed

Comment: Look EDIT 2. Try initialize variable in directive

Comment: Nope, Again didnt work I'll try the ng-if method now and report back.

Comment: Try: <editable ng-init="option={title:''};" model="option.title">{{option.title | Test}}</editable>

Comment: That worked, Update the answer, and i'll award it :)

Answer (score 0):

content between the opening and closing tags of your directive will be fully replaced by the directive's template if you are not using tansclusion.

Comment: No..... It doesnt, I have this working elsewhere the exact, The difference is the {{}} tags between the editable tags have content inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
<editable model="option.title">{{option.title || 'Placeholder Text' | Test}}</editable>
```

-

```
 {{model || 'text before model updates' | filter}}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.